# ModelBinding for SelectListItem - How to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, selectlistitem

I cannot understand why my `SelectListItem` is posting with null. Here is my scenario:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public int SelectedCategoryId {get;set;
   public IList<Category> Categories {get;set}
   public IList<SelectListItem> CategoriesSelectListItem
   {
      get
      {              
           var list = (from item in Categories 
                 select new SelectListItem()
                 {
                      Text = item.Name,
                      Value = item.Id.ToString()
                 }).ToList();
           return list;
       }
       set { }
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   IList<Category> categs = repository.GetCategories();
   return View(new MyViewModel(){ Categories = categs });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)  // At this point model.Categories is null on postback
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid())
   {
      // Do some Logic
      return Content("Succes!");
   }
   return View(model); //Throw again the view if model state is not valid
}
```

The View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
   Layout=null;
}
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId,Model.CategoriesSelectListItem)
```

So how to keep binding on Model.Categories **WHITHOUT** `ViewData[""]` or `Session` variables?

Thank You!

## Update 1

Added the view

Comment: Does the view have `Categories` either displayed or in a hidden field?

Comment: No because in that way I should do it in a loop or something.

Comment: Not at all, just do `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Categories)` and it will get back to the server during the `POST`.

Comment: It does not, I have tryied it out. I knew that `@Html.HiddenFor()` keeps only primitive data types (int,string,char,bool) etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting a form, the information you are posting is the one in `input` fields.

Since, you have a `DropDownList` for model property `SelectedCategoryId`  (I suppose it is inside a Form block), the only field that will be posted is the selected value.

This is how things work in HTTP and Asp.Net MVC3. May be you came from normal ASP.NET where all the pages travel (is posted) to the server, and you get confused.

We usually just need the selected value, because the full dropdownlist is retrieved from database (or cached to avoid several trips to database) in each request. If you think about it, you want to know what the user select, the list you displayed to him you already know about it.

Comment: I concur with Romias  you need to understand that in html in order to submit any value, it must be inside the <form>..</form> tags (webforms has that by default by having form runat=server requirement.  But dont think that way, think raw client/server html form submission. In your case, you just want to keep values handy if you have to re-render the form  ViewData and Session data are appropriate here. If you want the values recreated from the client, then you could use hidden and serialize values ot json and then deserialize in POST method (or use a custom model binding)